# Python: Error importing textblob lib

Tags: python, textblob

Using windows 10
I've install textblob using "py -m pip install textblob".
I can import textblob, or from textblob import blob,word
But i cant: from textblobl import Textblob.
The error i get is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    from textblob import Textblob
ImportError: cannot import name 'Textblob'

Thanks.

Comment: wich version of textblob are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try whit this:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try change your file name TextBlob.py

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31300032)